# pylinter config for sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, pylint

I'm using sublime text 3.
Settings of pylinter:
`

```
// Ignore Pylint error types. Possible values:
// "R" : Refactor for a "good practice" metric violation
// "C" : Convention for coding standard violation
// "W" : Warning for stylistic problems, or minor programming issues
// "E" : Error for important programming issues (i.e. most probably bug)
// "F" : Fatal for errors which prevented further processing
"ignore": [],`
```

Suppose I want to ignore the warnings for R and C, how do I use these options?
I tried doing `"ignore": ["RC"],` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`["R", "C"]` should be the correct method.